# Water supplies needed during travel to mars

Tags: mars, water

Could architectures seeking human missions to Mars not put caches of water in orbit around Earth prior to launching of a manned mission?

This would allow a later-launched manned mission to dock with and collect from the water caches placed in orbit, thus needing less thrust to get underway towards the destination.

Comment: Yes, the idea of making separate launches, and then "assembling" the overall spacecraft - is a great idea.  Many plans involve exactly this.  (Note that it applies to everything, not just water.  indeed water is only a minor concern.)   You've hit the nail on the head, congtrats!  :)

Comment: ISS and Apollo both used "assemble in space" steps. Apollo was re-assembly of things that lifted from Earth together, and ISS doesn't "get underway", but it is a proved and not just theoretical plan for big projects.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit vague since it seems to simply be proposing a solution, but I will do my best to give an explanation.

For the plan to travel to Mars, much of the plan revolves around what is called the space railroad, I think. Now while it is not a literal railroad, the plan calls for an orbiting lunar station, at which, assembly of a much larger rocket would be possible. This concept of assembling in space is a well know, but not commonly executed way of creating spacecraft. Until recently, the need for such large spacecraft has only really been limited to the ISS.

To bring in a semi-realisitic situation, in the video game, Kerbal Space Program, from what I understand, this is common practice for missions to other planets. But, since we have not sent a mission to another terrestrial body other than our moon that required the ability to get back, the need for a heavy spacecraft could be overcome by simply launching a bigger ship from the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is possible, and it's being looked at for various supplies, not just water. The SpaceX [BFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFR_(rocket)), for example, is designed to launch into Earth orbit, where the spaceship is refueled from tankers before it sets off to Mars.

But when you assemble a spacecraft in Earth orbit, you still have to accelerate the entire stack into a transfer orbit to Mars. So while it becomes easier to launch the stack in pieces, you still need to spend a lot of energy.

So NASA is looking into closed-loop environmental systems that can recycle most of the water. A [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_ECLSS) is installed on the ISS. This reduces the amount of water you need to bring along by a huge amount, making it a cheaper solution than multiple launches to supply water to the spacecraft.